# SpriteKit: SKShapeNode.calculateAccumulatedFrame returns a frame, which is bigger than its content

Tags: sprite-kit

I create a SKShapeNode rectangle with a fixed size using the following code

```
SKShapeNode *rect = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
CGRect accumulatedFrame = rect.calculateAccumulatedFrame;
```

Debugging the code above, the accumulatedFrame holds the values below:

```
origin=(x=-0.5, y=-0.5) size=(width=101, height=201)
```

Why is the calculated, accumulated frame bigger than the intended 100x200 ?

Thanks in advance for any hint :)

Code sample:

```
    SKShapeNode *rect = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
    CGRect accumulatedFrame = rect.calculateAccumulatedFrame;
    CGRect frame = rect.frame;
```

debugger returns *origin=(x=-0.5, y=-0.5) size=(width=201, height=101)* for the *accumulated frame* property

debugger returns *origin=(x=-0.5, y=-0.5) size=(width=201, height=101)* for the *frame* propery

Using an origin > (0,0) adds only 0,5 to width and height; seems, that sprite-kit returns an accumulated frame, which really contains the node(s) and adds 0.5, so none of the node borders intersects the border of the accumulated frame. Didn't find anything about it in the api reference...

Comment: check if the frame is 1x1 larger for any size

Comment: Seems to be the same for other sizes as well: `CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 15)` results in _origin=(x=-0.5, y=-0.5) size=(width=32, height=14)_. Using other origins e.g. `CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 15)`,  the calculated accumulated frame is _origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=30.5, height=25.5)_; it seems, that in this case, only 0.5x0.5 is added.

Comment: you run accumulatedframe on the shape node and it has no other child nodes, right? Does accumulatedframe differ from the frame property or are they the same?

Comment: Right, the SKShapeNode has no child nodes, and i run calculateAccumulatedFrame on this shape node. The the frame property returns the same 'modified' values... i added the code above in the origin question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue you are dealing with is that if you have a `strokeColor` defined, that border stroke adds to size of the rectangle.

Try this code :

```
SKShapeNode *rect = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
rect.strokeColor = nil;
```

You have to look at the stroke as being additive, and adding to the dimensions of your shape.

Comment: Resolved my issue! Wasn't aware, that spritekit added a border per default and - due to the fact, that I've chosen color WHITE to draw my rectangle and the default strokeColor is _"UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1"_, in other words WHITE as well, I didn't recognize the border.